# Symfony 2.8: bundle aliases in parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

For a distributable Symfony bundle, I want to allow referencing resource files through `parameters.yml`.

I want to allow using bundle aliases, e.g. `@FoobarSomethingBundle/Resources/foo/bar.png` would resolve to `src/Foobar/SomethingBundle/Resources/foo/bar.png` using `Kernel::locateResource`.

But apparently I cannot use the leading `@` sign to indicate that the reference starts with an alias and is not a file system path per se. For example:

```
### app/config/parameters.yml
some.value : "@FoobarSomethingBundle/Resources/foo/bar.png"
```

Symfony would interpret it as a *service* alias, and clearing the cache would fail with:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                          
You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to other services (reference to service "foobarsomethingbundle/resources/foo/bar.png" found in "/some.value").
```

Hence my question: Is there a feature or at least a convention on how to reference bundle aliases in config files, and maybe even resolve them on the fly?

Or maybe there’s a way to inject parameters “literally”, e.g. when I pass `"%some.value%"` as argument to a service, it would not try to resolve it as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use double @ sign for that

```
### app/config/parameters.yml
some.value : "@@FoobarSomethingBundle/Resources/foo/bar.png"
```

Comment: I guess that’s a viable solution, though it looks a bit ugly. I’ll accept it for now, still hoping that there’s a better way. ;)